# kali php problem

Tags: php, errors, fatal-error, scripts, linux

hello everyone I download a php script and when I try to run it kali show me this message:
PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /home/kali/fakecall/call.php on line 82

my kali php version is PHP 8.1.5

how can I fix it

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The use of curly braces (`{}`) in accessing an array index or string offset was deprecated in PHP 7.4 and later versions. You need to use square brackets (`[]`) instead. Update the code on line 82 (or there about) in call.php to fix the offending use of `{}`.